# NoMethodError: undefined method `except' for Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

While using except on Hash in Ruby,

```
d = {}
d["a"]=1234
d["b"]=34 
d["c"]=3 
d.except(:b,:c)
```

I am getting NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `except' for {"a"=>1234, "b"=>34, "c"=>3}:Hash  from (irb):6    from
/Users/niranjan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where do you see a method called except?

Comment: Error messages, as it this case, often tell you precisely what the problem is. Here it says that an instance of the class `Hash` does not have a *method* `except`, which means that the class `Hash` does not have an *instance method* by that name. Of course, just because you don't find it among in the [docs for Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) doesn't mean it isn't inherited from one of `Hash`'s ancestors (`Hash.ancestors #=> [Hash, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`). However, `Hash.instance_methods.include?(:except) #=> false` confirms it isn't inherited either.

Comment: you should said in rails.

Comment: @pangpang You made an edit that has changed the question completely and made it senseless. The error was raised precisely because Rails-related library was not loaded. So lacking of the tag ruby-on-rails was crucial.

Comment: Why so many downvotes??

Comment: @harshs08 This is no different from saying "`"foo".bar_baz` raises an error that says there is no method `bar_baz`. What am I doing wrong?" The answer is obviously, **you are using a method that does not exist**.

Comment: @sawa thanks for explaining, I got the rationale behind the downvotes . Just was trying to understand some of the reasons  what makes a good question good or bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`except`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) is a Rails method ([ActiveSupport](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#working-with-keys) to be exact). Your code does not reproduce that error when executing in Rails console:

```
> d = {}
# => {} 
> d["a"]=1234
# => 1234 
> d["b"]=34 
# => 34 
> d["c"]=3 
# => 3 
> d.except(:b,:c)
# => {"a"=>1234, "b"=>34, "c"=>3}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Hash#except`. You can implement it as follows:

```
d.reject { |k, v| ["b", "c"].include? k }
# => {"a"=>1234}
```

Note that it is not a Hash with indifferent access; `"b"` is not the same thing as `:b`.

Answer (score 1):

`Hash#except` will be in Ruby 3

```
h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
p h.except(:a) #=> {:b=>2, :c=>3}
```

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/09/25/ruby-3-0-0-preview1-released/

Answer (score 0):

As they have said above, there is no method 'except' meaning you have not defined 'except' anywhere in this code. If you need a refresher on how to build Hashes, a good one is: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm